# PresentViewController presents compile error in static/class functions

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, compiler-errors, static-methods, presentviewcontroller

I have a menu bar which I want to use on every page(`UIViewController`) in an app.  So I figured I'd just write it once and use it on all the pages, instead of reproducing the same code on every page. To go about that, I created a new class which extends `UIViewController`(named it `MenuBarViewController`), with its own `XIB` file, created a function within that class which contains the code for generating the menubar, and just make a call to that function in any `UIViewController` where I want to place the menubar.  Seems to work pretty seemlessly, but I run into problems when I tried to create some helper functions within the `MenuBarViewController` class, which trigger a navigation to another view, when one of the menu icons is tapped.  I will include a simplified version of the code I'm working with below which illustrates the entirety of the problem.

```
class MenuBarViewController: UIViewController {

    func menuBar(viewController:UIViewController){

        let menuBar = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,20 ))
        menuBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        viewController.view.addSubview(menuBar) //Add the newly created view to the main view(self)
        //Add an icon view to the menubar
        let iconView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(5,0,5,5))
        menuBar.addSubview(iconView)

        //Add a gesture recognizer for the icon view
        iconView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        let tapHomeButton = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(MenuBarViewController.goToHomeView(_:)))
        iconView.addGestureRecognizer(tapHomeButton)

        //Add an icon to the icon view
        let iconImageName = UIImage(named:"home.png")!
        iconView.image = iconImageName
    }

    //Helper function to handle the gesture recognizer, helps transition to another view
    func goToHomeView(sender: UIImageView!) {
        appData.lastView = "GameViewController"
        let settingsVC = SettingsViewController(nibName:     "SettingsViewController", bundle: nil)
        presentViewController(settingsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Now when I tap on the icon, there is no response. So I figured I'd declare the class functions(`menuBar` and `goToHomeView`) as either "`class`" or "`static`" funcs, and then call the menu bar directly with the class name. But then I get this compile error "extra argument '`animated`' in call" on the this line:

```
presentViewController(settingsVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So something must be wrong with the `presentViewController` method when it is declared within a static or class function because when I have the `goToHomeView` function just do something as simple as printing some text, it works fine.  So I'm at a total loss at this point. What to do? Am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Comment: `presentViewController` is an instance method, so you can't call it from a class method where you don't have an instance.

Comment: Using this approach you will end up with an infinitely deep set of view controllers, each presented modally on top of one another.  You should probably structure your menu bar to be a container view controller and simply switch out the visible view controller, much like a tabbar controller does

Comment: Paulw11 can you elaborate a little more on what your meant by "switch out the visible view controller"?